# How to redirect customer to assigned Magento website after system auto-login

Tags: magento, events

I have a Magento install with a default website and multiple 'franchise' websites.

My question is, how can I capture the event when a customer returns to the website after being away and is auto-logged in via Magento's persistent login mechanism? I would like to capture that event, load the customer, check if they are in the correct website id, then redirect them if they are not.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with the assigned website redirect Corgalore?

Comment: I did figure it out eventually. I'll post my solution later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, you must register an event in your /app/code/local/Extension/Module/etc/config.xml like this:

```
<customer_session_init>
        <observers>
          <sessioninit_handler>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Extension_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>on_customer_session_init</method>
          </sessioninit_handler>
        </observers>
</customer_session_init>
```

Then create an Observer method in /app/code/local/Extension/Module/Model/Observer.php like so:

```
/*
** on customer session init, checks for current website id and redirects if no-match
*/
public function on_customer_session_init(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $customer = $observer->customer_session->getCustomer();
    $customer_website_id = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    $current_website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

    if ($customer_website_id != $current_website_id){
        $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($customer_website_id);
        $request = $this->_getRequest();
        $response = $this->_getResponse();

        $url = $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl().substr($request->getRequestString(), 1);
        $response->setRedirect($url);
    }

    return $this;
}
```